# How to calculate rigid geotransform (scaling and rotation only) from GCPs in Python

Tags: python, georeferencing

I've been georeferencing images using automatically detected GCPs using Rasterio but it only has Affine transforms. I'm aware that QGIS has some rigid transforms as an option in the Georeferencer tool but I can't find any pure Python equivalent.

I'm interested in georeferencing the image by scaling it and rotating it but I do not want to distort/warp it. I have been using Affine transformations which have led to slight warping/shearing wherein parts of the image are accurate but other parts are inaccurate. I am assuming the image was taken at nadir and I want the image to have consistent errors.

Is anyone familiar with calculating a rigid geotransform from GCPs in a pure Python environment?